# Changing a Image while the app is running?

Tags: android, image, button, imageview, onclicklistener

I am changing the `ImageView` background to change every time you press the `button`. I tried switching `setBackGround` to `setImageResource` but it makes me change the imageview to a constant. I don't know if make imageview a constant will help or if there is a other way of doing it.

This is what i have so far.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dummy_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dummy_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setImageResource instead:

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawablename);
```

For changing the image every time:

First declare a array of imageIds

```
public Integer[] imageIds = {
        R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3 
};
```

then on your onClick method

```
    int i = 0;
    img.setImageResource(imageIds[i]);
    i = i+1;
```

With this, when you first click it gets the item 1, then i will become 1. Second time you press, the image will become the second one, and the i will become 2. If you want to get a random one every time. You need to declare a Random.